# Protractor "restartBrowserBetweenTests: true" restart browser, but don't run test after this

Tags: testing, browser, protractor, restart

I need to restart browser after each "it" (test), for this reason I write "restartBrowserBetweenTests: true" in protractor.config file. Now after first "it" (test) finished, browser closed and opened again (open website that I write in "beforeEach", but next "it" (test) is not run.

What I do wrong? I will be happy for any advice.

I use "protractor": "2.5.1".

Thanks!

Added:

```
beforeEach(function () {
    browserUtil.navigateTo(browserUtil.url.main); 
    loginPage.loginAsSample();
});

afterEach(function(){
    browserUtil.deleteCookies();
});

it("'Delete' button is inactive if there are no projects in the list", function() {
    projectPage.clickOnProjectButton();

    expect(projectPage.isProjectPageFormVisibility(true)).toBe(true);
    expect(projectPage.isDeleteBtnDisable()).toBe(true);
});

it("Create new project with template 'A'", function() {
    projectPage.clickOnNewProjectBtn();
    projectPage.clickOnAProject();
    projectPage.clickOnOkBtnProject();

    expect(projectPage.isOpenedProjectVisibility(true)).toBe(true);
});
```

Comment: can you please ping the spec code which contains the it() and beforeEach()

Comment: I added, please look.
Without browser restart everything works fine.

Comment: Can you add logic to log out from application  in afterEach() method and try it will work

Answer (score 1):

I've never utilized `restartBrowserBetweenTests: true`, but this works for me:

in protractor.conf, remove `restartBrowserBetweenTests: true`

in test.spec.js, modify `beforeEach` and `afterEach`

```
beforeEach(function () {
    browser.get(browserUtil.url.main);
});

afterEach(function () {
    browser.manage().deleteAllCookies();
});
```

Being that you're utilizing a page object structure for your tests, you could/would want to encapsulate `browser.get(browser.browserUtil.url.main);` into you're page object.

Where ProjectPage is defined, I'd add :

```
this.refreshPage = function () {
     browser.get(browserUtil.url.main);
};
```

If you go with this approach, you'd change the call on `beforeEach` to :

```
beforeEach(function () {
    projectPage.refresh();
});
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer!

In my browserUtils.js I have written methods for browserUtil.deleteCookies() and browserUtil.navigateTo() like you showed.

But if my test fails because of unexpected error and I want to refresh page, my browser (chrome) stack with popup "Do you want to leave this site?" and all test after this popup fails. That's why I want to close and open browser after each test, not just refresh page. I have no idea how to solve this problem with another method.